# Notes crash when i try download file from Xpage page which i opened in Notes client

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, hcl-notes

Notes crash when i try to download file from Xpage page which i opened in Notes client.
This is simple filedownload control.
When I open Xpage in browser I can download this file.
When I open Form i can download this attachment.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your question? Sounds like a problem for HCL support.

Comment: Maybe I must change something config in notes.ini or something else?

Comment: Check for the Ext_Mgr_Addins entry in notes.ini if there is one. That's where anti-virus and other third-party products that have the potential to crash the Notes client would be hooked in.  If there is anything there, back it up and remove it, then try again.

Comment: If there is no Ext_Mgr_Addins line in notes.ini, then I always start with the assumption that If the Notes client crashes, it's a bug. HCL support will ask you to send files from the IBM_Technial_Support folder that were generated during the crash. If you update your post with details (the first 50-ish lines from the Fatal Thread section) from the .NSD file that matches the timestamp of your crash, people here may be able to help you, but HCL is much more likely to be able to help.

Comment: FYI I have the same problem on any client upgraded to Notes 11 when using XPiNC.

Comment: You should report this to HCL using their customer support site at https://support.hcltechsw.com/csm?id=csm_index